# Can I not package gcm library into the apk?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I want to use Google Cloud Messaging in my app, under the guidance of the gcm tutorial, it works. But I have another idea, that is can I not package gcm library into the apk, beacause I think in the android platform it will integrate. Therefore I change the 'compile' to 'provided' in the `dependencies` in `build.gradle` and add the `<use-library>` attribute in `AndroidMenifest.xml`

```
compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.5.0') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
```

Unfortunately, I failed because I meet a `ClassNotFound` Exception, so I think it doesn't work if I don't package gcm library into the apk.

However, I find the WeChat app also has gcm push, so I decompile WeChatxxx.apk with [enjarify](https://github.com/google/enjarify) to investigate how WeChat implements this function. The weird thing is that I do not find the gcm package in its decompiled jar file(I think gcm library can not be proguard-ed, can it?).

So can google cloud messaging work without gcm library packaging into the apk, is it unable to do so or I didn't find the gcm pacakge in the WeChat apk.

Answer (score 0):

I finally find the WeChat also include gcm library in its apk file, but it is hidden in in a second `classes.dex` file in `assets/` folder. So I think the third party apps can not package without include gcm library if then want to integrated google cloud messaging.